# how to upload files through updateview django

Tags: django

I'm trying to use a view based on `UpdateView` to update an entity which has a file field. The text updates but the file is not getting uploaded.

When I created the article I used a function view and I did:

```
form=ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
...
form.save
```

I want to do the same using a class based on `UpdateView` but I don't know how, any suggestions?

Model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=256)
    content=models.TextField()
    thumbnail=models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name,null=True,blank=True)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

View:

```
class update_article(UpdateView):
    model = Article
    fields = ['title','content','thumbnail']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user_articles')  

    template_name = 'article/update_article.html'
```

Template `update_article.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{form.as_p}}
  <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Edit: I've solved it, it turn out that the files were getting uploaded in the media root and i was trying to access them in the static root

Comment: The code looks fine, are there any errors at all? Are you sure `get_upload_file_name` is returning what you expect? Have you ran the necessary migrations?

Comment: it turns out that the files were getting uploaded in the media root and i was searching them in static root, i changed the media root to match the static root and now it's ok

Comment: glad you could work it out